# Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have installed Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 18.04 (system version Python 3.6.9) using [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). I want to install a numerical package "Firedrake" using Python3.10. Firedrake does not install with the default Python version (3.6.9). When I issue the command:
`python3.10 firedrake-install` (firedrake-install is the script to install firedrake), python3.10 still tries to using the default python version (3.6.9) and I end up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/salil/firedrake-install", line 19, in
from pkg_resources import parse_version
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 77, in
import('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in
from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 672, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/init.py", line 43, in load_module
import(extant)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in
collections.MutableMapping.register(ParseResults)
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I am not that familiar with Python and hence do not how to fix this error; i.e. how to force python3.10 to use /usr/lib/python3.10.

Comment: What do `type -a python3.10` and `python3.10 --version` output?

Comment: What command did you run to install Python 3.10? It looks like its stdlib is missing.

Comment: Oops, I thought `pkg_resources` was part of the stdlib but evidently not. I think you actually need to install prerequisites for Firedrake.

Comment: @Dennis `type -a python3.10` returns python3.10 is /usr/bin/python3.10 and `python3.10 --version` returns Python 3.10.8

Comment: Why do you think 3.6.9 is being run? I don't see any mention of that in the traceback. I think wjandrea is probably right. You are probably missing some prereqs or your libs haven't been updated for 3.10. What I often have to do is some `pip install` commands after I install a new version of Python.

Comment: @Dennis: Issuing the command `python3 --version` returns Python 3.6.9

Comment: You might be able to fix that using [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem I was having was related to this [bug] (https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2988). I was able to resolve the issue with:
`git clone https://github.com/pypa/setuptools.git && cd setuptools && sudo python3.10 setup.py install` followed by
`curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10`

To be fair, I do not understand the details of the bug but the above two commands solved my problem.